# Syntax error in mySql to create Procedures

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, xampp, mariadb

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `unitstoamount`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `unitstoamount`( IN units INT(14) , OUT result INT(14))
BEGIN

    DECLARE a INT(14) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE b INT(14) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE c INT(14) DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT twohundred FROM unitsRate INTO a ;
    SELECT fivehundred FROM unitsRate INTO b ;
    SELECT thousand FROM unitsRate INTO c  ;

    IF units<200
    then
        SELECT a*units INTO result;

    ELSEIF units<500
    then
        SELECT (a*200)+(b*(units-200)) INTO result;
    ELSEIF units > 500
    then
        SELECT (a*200)+(b*(300))+(c*(units-500)) INTO result;
    END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: you don't need to use `SELECT` to assign variables, use `SET result = a * units;`

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Did you do `DELIMITER $$` before the procedure?

Comment: And you can do the first three selects in one: `SELECT twohundred, fivehundred, thousand FROM unitsRate INTO a, b, c`

Comment: why a procedure?, this looks much more like a function.

Comment: BTW, you never set result if `units = 500`. The last block should probably just be `ELSE` without a condition.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `unitstoamount`( IN units INT(14) , ' at line 5

Comment: This is the main error

Answer (score 0):

You have set the DELIMITER to be `$$`. So, you should use it also in the `DROP PROCEDURE` statement:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `unitstoamount`
$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `unitstoamount`( IN units INT(14) , OUT result INT(14))
...
```